# Playground not executing code

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Been through a few posts about this to no resolve.  No code I write executes in the right hand pane, I have however been able to produce errors (on purpose) but still no output when it's the most basic of code.

Details:

-High Sierra 10.13.6
-Attempted in Xcode 9 (+ fresh install) and even downloaded 10 Beta, same results
-Tried a simple 'hello world' without output, also downloaded 'Intro to Swift' playground files straight from Apple that will not run.
-Dragged the screens, toggled different panes off and on, multiple restarts
-Ran in to an issue where no editor even displays in 10 beta from a fresh blank playground instance

Comment: welcome to SO, please consult this page and edit your question before it is tagged to be removed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So I do not have permission to edit the question, or delete it so I can repost with a correct title.  Title should read 'Why is Xcode playground not executing code?'

Comment: if you can be more specific I can edit it for you, code not working is not really specific

Comment: Thanks Ibo it's not the code, it's a simple hello world output.  I even downloaded basic tutorials as a test from Apple with no luck https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=intro-app-dev-curriculum-swift4

The exact same code, even far more complex code I've written is executing outside out playground